# Is it possible for all of the smooth/continuous curves in $R^3$ to form a Hilbert space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Under which condition can it form a Hilbert space? Or what space can it form?

You can write down certain condition to make it to be a Hilbert space, e.g., Let $$p(t)=[x(t),y(t),z(t)]^T\in \text{R}^3$$ and $$\langle p_1(t),p_2(t)\rangle =\int_{t_0}^{t_f}p_1(t)^Tp_2(t)\mathrm{d}t<+\infty.$$

Clarify: Smooth can mean either continuous or continuity up to the first/second or even higher order.

Complex version: What about all of the smooth curves in $\operatorname{SE}(3)$, the Special Euclidean group (or rigid body transformation group)?

Comment: This is a good question for [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com), but, as @RobertIsrael's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/377893) indicates, it is standard graduate-level material, not research-level mathematics, and so does not belong here.

Comment: @LSpice My MSE account was limited, and I am only allowed to ask questions here:(

Answer (score 2):

The continuous or smooth functions from a closed interval to $\mathbb R^3$ form an inner product space, but it is not a Hilbert space because it is not complete.  The $L^2$ functions from an interval to $\mathbb R^3$ form a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a closed interval of the real line and let $E$ be a finite dimensional Euclidean space then we have the vector space:

> $C[I,E] := Top[I,E]$

of all continuous maps from $I$ to $E$. After imposing the uniform norm on this space, this is a normed space, and in fact a Banach space called the classical Weiner space used in studies of Brownian motion. It's not a Hilbert space.

The complex variant of this is important in the study of path integrals a la Feynman where the usual theory of Brownian motion fails and still remains an important research direction.